# Moments of vibrating string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vibrations, string, moment

I have to calculate first 10 moments for vibrating string with damping, but I don't know how to do it. I read about moments and in definition they mention linear system $$x'=Ax+Bu, \qquad y=Cx$$ with [transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) $$W(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B.$$ Then kth moment of a system above is $$C(sI-A)^{-(k+1)}B.$$ But for a vibrating string I know only wave equation $$Mx''+Cx'+Kx=b(t).$$ How to transform it to linear system?

Comment: What is your definition of "$n$th moment of vibrating string"? I've never before heard the term *moment* in this context.

Comment: I don't have definition for nth moment of vibrating string. I'm not even sure it can be done. Maybe if I knew transfer function for vibrating string, but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I believe this is a control theory terminology and comes from the fact that one uses the expression to calculate the moments of the output process given an assumption that the input is unit variance, white Gaussian noise.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to define a few state variables. Here is the standard, control theory recipe that should get you going:

Let $x_1(t) = x(t)$ and $x_2(t) = \dot{x_1}(t)$. Then your vibrating string equation becomes $M \mathrm{d}_t x_2(t) + C x_2(t) + K x_1(t) = b(t)$. That is:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\,t} \left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-\frac{K}{M}&-\frac{C}{M}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right) +\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\\frac{1}{M}\end{array}\right) b(t)$$

and, if you want to learn about the behaviour of $x(t)$ in response to $b(t)$ (*i.e.* think of $x(t)$ as the output, $b(t)$ as the input), you define your output equation as:

$$y = (1,\,0)\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right)$$

So now, in the standard control theory notation of your first equation:

$$\dot{\vec{x}} = \mathbf{A} \vec{x} + \mathbf{B}\,\vec{u};\quad\vec{y} = \mathbf{C}\vec{x}$$

you can now make the following identifications:

$$\mathbf{A} =\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-\frac{K}{M}&-\frac{C}{M}\end{array}\right)$$
$$\mathbf{B} = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\\frac{1}{M}\end{array}\right)$$
$$\mathbf{C} = (1,\,0)$$
$$y(t) = x_1(t);\quad u(t) = b(t)$$

and now you should be set to go. The Laplace transform transfer function is then, as you say, $\mathbf{C}(s\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{B}$, which, for your single input, single output (SISO) system, is a simple scalar transfer function. The frequency response, naturally, is given by putting $s=i\,\omega$, where $\omega$ is the natural frequency. The system's natural frequencies are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$.