# Transfer function of vibrating string

Tags: vibrations

I need to find moments of vibrating string and I think that transfer function could be useful for this, but I don't know transfer function of vibrating string. Can someone give me some idea how to find it?

Comment: Dear Latifa - welcome to Physics SE - the one with the Mexican Hat Potential logo. I think you should merge this question with your other as we don't want a proliferation of duplicate questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moments of vibrating string](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137358/)